# How can I assign value to a field?

Tags: php

How can I assign the value 1990 to born_year in $u0? I get an error massage saying Invalid text string.

```
 <?php if($u0->i_sex=='98') { ?>    
    $u0->born_year =1990;
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All PHP inside the " <?php ?>" tag

```
<?php 
 if($u0->i_sex=='98') { 
    $u0->born_year =1990;
 } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP outside of the PHP tags.

- `<?php` is used at the start of your PHP code.
- `?>` is used at the end of your PHP code.

Try:

```php
<?php 
  if($u0->i_sex=='98') {  
    $u0->born_year =1990;
  } 
?>
```